# iTween consider up vector of transforms

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using iTween.MoveTo and for the "path" argument, I give an array of transforms. Though the transforms are placed on a sphere. The object moves very nicely over the path, but it stays oriented upwards instead of properly oriented on the sphere.

[image]

I tried using the "lookat" argument and giving that the center of my sphere and that works (after tweaking my character a bit that if it looks at the center it's actually standing on it) but then he won't look ahead on the path.

So, is there any way I can make iTween to take the up vector of the transforms into account?

Thanks!

Comment: Currently I'm just using the "PointOnPath" in the Update of my object and then just add a proper rotation there. Though would still love to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to disable the "lookat" and turn a flag on when the iTween is happening ( I suggest a Coroutine that uses WaitForSeconds for the duration of the tween ).

Then, on your Update/FixedUpdate routine, you can use the following code:

```
outSideObjectTransform.forward = outSideObjectTransform.position - lookTarget.position;
```

This will make the outsideObject have it's **forward** axis direction going away from the center object. The same can be said for any of the axis.

Also, if you want the exact opposite ( that the object looks towards it's "look target") , just replace the subtraction of the two Vectors with an addition.

I hope this helps.